# Order By Numeric, Alphabetically, and Alphanumeric with special characters

Tags: postgresql, sorting, sql-order-by, alphanumeric

Currently I'm trying to take a list of values from my table and order them alphanumerically so they appear from number to letters. For example I have this data set:

```
3
8
0.64
0.64 + 2.8
70
90
AK
050LL (Beta)
070
PQ
W3
0.5
0.6
0.8
040
070
1.2
1.5
1.6
100
150
187
2.8
250
3.0
6.3
800
8mm
```

And I want it to print 0.5 first and then W3 last. I am using an Lpad to grab the data, but it displays like shown above, with no ordering. Is there a way I can sort these by numbers, then numbers+letters, finally letters in PostgreSQL? Do I need to have some special clause for the ordering to be correct?

The SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data_table
ORDER BY LPAD(parameter_type, 10) ASC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: a basic `ORDER BY your_text_column` will provide the quite expected result see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f59de196a5189f8ab2325f081f05e007)

Comment: That does work, but it's not very dynamic. Is there a way to do it without specifying every filed in the column?

Comment: Yes sure, you can a query on your table to get the list dynamically. This query depends on your table definition. Can you share it ?